# How to check if OleDbDataReader is empty?

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, oledbdatareader

This is the code i am using to select Maximum **RollNo** based on **Class** field value.
But when there is no data about **Class** Field in Table. Then Error is generated.

```
using (var conn = new OleDbConnection(DatabaseObjects.ConnectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                command = new OleDbCommand("select max(RollNo) as Roll from Students where Class = '"+cmbClass.Text+"'", conn);
                OleDbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
                if (!dr.IsDBNull(0))
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        i = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Roll"]);
                    }
                }
```

**InvalidOperation Exception** is occurring. I want to get value of RollNo if data is available in Table. If data is not available in Table then what should I do?

Comment: You’re trying to access the row before you read it, with `if (!dr.IsDBNull(0))`

Comment: Then what i should do?

Comment: Please, for your own sake... Use parameters and not string concatenation

Comment: I will use now parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are inversing the steps :

- open the connection;
- check is there is comming data;
- check if the value is not null;
- read the data;

try this :

```
while (dr.Read())
   {
       if (!dr.IsDBNull(0))
          {
            i = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Roll"]);
          }
   }
```

while your are attending just single value, use executeScalar to get the value ;

```
  conn.Open();          
  command = new OleDbCommand("select isnull(max(RollNo),-1) as Roll from Students where Class = '"+cmbClass.Text+"'", conn);
  int rollNo = (int) command.ExecuteScallar();
  if(rollno !=-1)
  {
     // TODO :
  }
```

Comment: if(rollno !=-2) why you have use -2?

Comment: when i executed your given code, it gives OleDbException.

Comment: Additional information: Wrong number of arguments used with function in query expression 'isnull(max(RollNo),-1'.

Comment: Sorry bro, i want to write {-1}, and i forgot the ')' in the query, sorry

Comment: it gives error at this line [ int rollNo = (int) command.ExecuteScallar(); ] 
specified cast is not valid.

Comment: if you are using access, try this `select IIF(Isnull(max(RollNo)),-1,max(RollNo)) from ..... 
where class = value_that_you_want group by Class, RollNo`